# How do I use lapply or sapply for boostraping or KM calculations on three different DFs when functions are nested?

Tags: r, nested, lapply, sapply, bootstrapping

**I want to run a bootstrap (k=10,000) and Kaplan-Meier calculations on the numeric column of three different data frames using lapply or sapply when functions are nested.**

I have defined three functions to use as arguments in the command for boostrapping.
One function returns a set of predefined quantiles, another the median, and a thrid a 95% confidence interval for the median. Bootstrapping fails altogether. The error I get for bootstrapping reads, **"Error in x[, "Result", drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions"**

KM only completes for the first data frame on the list (df).

I am using the **boot** and **NADA2** libraries for the calculations.

Below is a REPREX of the data, functions, and commands:

```
library(boot)
library(wakefield)

#Generate three random datasets as data frames for example

#df
Result <- rnorm(1000,10,1)
Cens <- r_sample_logical(1000, name = "Cens")  
df <- data.frame(Result,Cens)

#df1
Result <- rnorm(1000,10,1)
Cens <- r_sample_logical(1000, name = "Cens")  
df1 <- data.frame(Result,Cens)

#df2
Result <- rnorm(1000,10,1)
Cens <- r_sample_logical(1000, name = "Cens")  
df2 <- data.frame(Result,Cens)

x <- c(df, df1, df2)

#I know I can use built-in R base functions in the following way:

lapply(x, quantile)
sapply(x, quantile)

#How do I use lapply and sapply when funtions are nested like in the example below?

#Bootstrap
medianfun <- function(x, i){
  d <- x[i, ]
  return(median(d))   
}
meanfun <- function(x, i){
  d <- x[i, ]
  return(mean(d))   
}
quantfun <- function(x, i){
  d <- x[i, ]
  return(quantile(d, c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.95)))   
}

set.seed(1234)
bo.quant<- boot(x[, "Result", drop = FALSE], statistic=quantfun, R=10000)
bo.quant
bo.median <- boot(x[, "Result", drop = FALSE], statistic=medianfun, R=10000)
bo.median
bo.95ci.df <- boot.ci(bo.median, conf=0.95, type="bca")
bo.95ci.df

#Kaplan Meier
library(NADA2)
tddt.km = cfit(x$Result,x$Censored, qtls = c(.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.8,.845,.85,.90,.95))
tddt.km
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use `list` instead of `c` and give the data frames names like so:

```
x <- list(df=df, df1=df1, df2=df2)
```

Then adapt your functions to lists:

```
#Bootstrap
medianfun <- function(x, i) {
  d <- x[i]
  return(median(d))   
}
meanfun <- function(x, i) {
  d <- x[i]
  return(mean(d))   
}
quantfun <- function(x, i) {
  d <- x[i]
  return(quantile(d, c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95)))   
}
```

This allows you to use `lapply` to get the results also in lists:

```
set.seed(1234)
R <- 199
bo.quant <- lapply(x, function(z) boot(z$Result, statistic=quantfun, R=R))
bo.quant$df  ## access list `df`. `df1` and `df2` accordingly
# ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
# 
# 
# Call:
#   boot(data = z$Result, statistic = quantfun, R = R)
# 
# 
# Bootstrap Statistics :
#   original        bias    std. error
# t1*   8.710887 -1.294426e-02  0.04987613
# t2*   9.188977 -2.396393e-02  0.06190039
# t3*   9.454297  8.847132e-03  0.03356391
# t4*   9.717689  9.789525e-03  0.04214934
# t5*   9.998288 -7.193749e-04  0.04270117
# t6*  10.259694 -1.568850e-04  0.03849390
# t7*  10.558218  4.143536e-03  0.05029767
# t8*  10.876818  7.381331e-03  0.04242551
# t9*  11.297995 -2.533015e-03  0.05898180
# t10* 11.706104  7.215891e-05  0.08313804

bo.median <- lapply(x, function(z) boot(z$Result, statistic=medianfun, R=R))
bo.median$df

bo.95ci.df <- boot.ci(bo.median, conf=0.95, type="bca")
bo.95ci.df
# ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
# 
# 
# Call:
#   boot(data = z$Result, statistic = medianfun, R = R)
# 
# 
# Bootstrap Statistics :
#   original       bias    std. error
# t1* 9.998288 -0.005605121  0.04629431

#Kaplan Meier
library(NADA2)
tddt.km <- lapply(x, function(z) 
  cfit(z$Result, z$Cens, qtls=c(.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .8, .845, .85, .90, .95),
  Cdf=FALSE, printstat=FALSE))
tddt.km$df
# N PctND Conf KMmean  KMsd KMmedian LCLmean UCLmean LCLmedian UCLmedian   Q10   Q20    Q30   Q40    Q50    Q80  Q84.5    Q85    Q90    Q95
# 1000  49.9   95  9.321 1.225   <9.365   9.294   9.348     9.257     9.442 7.633 8.207 <8.652 8.997 <9.365 <10.42 <10.64 <10.67 <10.94 <11.31
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work for the first element of the list (i.e., df only). Would I then use a **for loop or lapply** to iterate through each of the three elements (data frames) in the list?

Comment: @user11036517 See update!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is awesome. I also had not noticed I was using "c" instead of "list".

Comment: @user11036517 `c` isn't completely wrong, `list` just nests the data frames one level deeper, which is what we want. Please consider to [mark answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).